# How to reference Projects in aptana studio 3

Tags: php, javascript, aptana3

Hi I am creating a web project. For that i want to keep the scripts in a separate project and the php files in separate project. I am using aptana studio 3 as the IDE.

There is an option -> Reference Project. I did that but how to proceed next. I am not able to find anything in the aptana studio documentation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking in Eclipse (and thus in Aptana, since they're pretty much the same thing) you want just one project to encompass all your code.  It makes things MUCH easier that way, because switching projects is a bit of a pain.  Therefore, my recommendation is that you re-consider your plan, because it will probably make your life difficult later.

But, if you really want to do it, this question has already been answered here on SO:

[How can I reference another project in Eclipse Java EE projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580576/how-can-i-reference-another-project-in-eclipse-java-ee-projects)

[How to work with referenced projects in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443286/how-to-work-with-referenced-projects-in-eclipse)